# showing page preloader only once?

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, preloader

What I'd like to achieve is to load this only once, when the user first visits the page and then never again until they clear their cache

**HTML:**

```
<div id="preloader">
<div id="status>loading</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).load(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#status').fadeOut();
    $('#preloader') delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
    $('body').delay(350).css({
        'overlow': 'visible'
    });
})
```

Comment: Cache? This would be easier with LocalStorage. Do you mean that?

Comment: How exactly would a user clear their cache? (just to be sure we are talking about the same thing)

Comment: @musefan through their browser

Comment: yeah... but how. Do you mean the kind of cache you can clear with CTRL + F5? Or are you referring to something else, like a cookie?

Comment: @musefan yes, by using cookies

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function() {

   //Check if user haven't seen loading screen
   if (localStorage.getItem('loading-screen') != null) {

       //show loading
       $('#status').fadeOut();
       $('#preloader')delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
       $('body').delay(350).css({'overlow':'visible');

       //Set info to localStorage that it has been seen
       localStorage.setItem('loading-screen', 'seen');
   }

});
```

---

**Deleting localStorage:**

```
localStorage.removeItem('loading-screen');
```

**Little introduction:**

```
localStorage.setItem('loading-screen', 'seen');
```

- `'loading-screen'` - key that you can use to get it later on
- `'seen'` - value of that key